# trouble with the preprocessor - when concatenating "name" and "=" as tokens

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Here is the code:

```
#define STR_CONCAT_IMPL(s1, s2) s1##s2
#define STR_CONCAT(s1, s2) STR_CONCAT_IMPL(s1, s2)
#define TOSTR_IMPL(x) #x
#define TOSTR(x) TOSTR_IMPL(x)
#define STR_CONCAT_TOSTR(s1, s2) TOSTR(STR_CONCAT(s1, s2))

int main() {
    const char* a = STR_CONCAT_TOSTR(name, p); // works
    const char* b = STR_CONCAT_TOSTR(name, =); // doesn't work
    return 0;
}
```

I need a string like `"name="` from `"name"` at compile time (runtime concatenation not an option) so I tried with my old macros but I get this error:

```
error: pasting "name" and "=" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

But when not using `=` but a normal character - it works.

How can I get this to work?

C++98 GCC/MSVC solution needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume you need a macro for this and can't just use the compiler itself.

Take advantage of adjacent string literals being concatenated:

```
#define STR_CONCAT_TOSTR(s1, s2) TOSTR(s1) TOSTR(s2)
```

In this case, `STR_CONCAT_TOSTR(name, =)` expands to `"name" "="`, which the compiler turns into `"name="`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `name=` isn't a token, it's two. So, unlike with `namep`, they can't be pasted to produce a single token.

All you need to do is define `STR_CONCAT_TOSTR` differently to concatenate the string literals of the starting tokens instead of trying to concatenate the tokens first:

```
#define STR_CONCAT_TOSTR(s1, s2) (TOSTR(s1) TOSTR(s2))
```

Comment: I recognize your avatar - epic concurrent stuff on github!